# What is different between snapshot and prevState, prevProps from componentDidUpdate in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I just started to studying React.

When learning LifeCycle and I wonder about `componentDidUpdate` method.

As I read `componentDidUpdate` method can have three params (`prevProps, prevState, snapshot`). If I can find out `prevState` from `componentDidUpdate` what is the `snapshot` for?

It may not important but I just got curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `componentDidUpdate` docs:

> If your component implements the `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` lifecycle
> (which is rare), the value it returns will be passed as a third
> “snapshot” parameter to `componentDidUpdate()`. Otherwise this parameter
> will be undefined.

[getSnapshotBeforeUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)

> `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` is invoked right before the most recently
> rendered output is committed to e.g. the DOM. It enables your
> component to capture some information from the DOM (e.g. scroll
> position) before it is potentially changed. Any value returned by this
> lifecycle will be passed as a parameter to `componentDidUpdate()`.
>
> This use case is not common, but it may occur in UIs like a chat
> thread that need to handle scroll position in a special way.
>
> A snapshot value (or `null`) should be returned.

Use-cases appear mostly related to querying the DOM, or anything that *can't* be derived from `state` or `props`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I also thought what the importance of snapshots are, but your explanation on "things that cannot be derived from `state` or `props` makes so much sense.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` with real use cases? Right now answer is not clear enough. @Drew Reese

Comment: @wayne Do you need something more than what is provided as an example in the official docs the answer links to?

Comment: I need some common use cases we can come across. @DrewReese

Comment: @wayne Instead of me dreaming up arbitrary examples that you may or may not find helpful it sort of sounds like you might have a specific issue that you are trying to use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` for and it might just be more beneficial for you to create a new SO post with details specific to your issue. If you do create a post feel free to ping me here in another comment with a link to it and I can take a look when available.